# Formik check if checkbox is checked

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am having the hardest time figuring out how to determine if the checkbox is checked using Formik and React. So far i am able to return the value of the checked box but can't seem to return true or false.

I am trying to add a class to the checkbox if it has been checked, which I can do if it has a value but when unchecked, it doesn't remove the class. I think i may be approaching this incorrectly...

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you

**Initial Values:**

```
const initialValues = {
  // step two
  processorOptions: [],
};
```

**processorOptions:**

```
const processorOptions = [
  { type: 'cc', value: 'test1', name: 'Test 1' },
  { type: 'cc', value: 'test2', name: 'Test 2' },
  { type: 'cc', value: 'test3', name: 'Test 3' },
];
```

**Custom Field Component:**

```
const Processors = () => {
  const { values } = useFormikContext();

  return (
    <>
      <FieldArray
        name='processorOptions'
        render={(arrayHelpers) => (
          <>
            {processorOptions.map((processorOption, index) => (
              <Col lg={4} key={index}>
                <div className='form-group'>
                  <div className='form-check'>
                    <label className={`onboard__processor-label ${processorOption.checked ? 'is-checked' : ''}`}>
                      <input
                        name='processorOptions'
                        type='checkbox'
                        value={processorOption.id}
                        checked={values.processorOptions.includes(processorOption.id)}
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          if (e.target.checked) {
                            arrayHelpers.push(processorOption.id);
                          } else {
                            const idx = values.processorOptions.indexOf(processorOption.id);
                            arrayHelpers.remove(idx);
                          }
                        }}
                      />
                      {processorOption.name}
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Col>
            ))}
          </>
        )}
      />
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(values.processorOptions, null, 2)}</pre>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: I've edited the code to an updated version of what I am now working with that appears to work just fine, still unable to determine if the checkbox is checked based off of TRUE or FALSE...